# kotlin(multiplatform) version 1.7.20 incompatibility with spring-boot and kotlin/js react

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to create a kotlin multiplatform project with spring-boot and kotlin/js react

This is the build.gradle.kts am using:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.4" apply false
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.14.RELEASE" apply false
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.7.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.20" apply false
}

group = "com.examples"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/kotlinx-html/maven")
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")
        apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")
        apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring")

        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }

        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
        withJava()
    }
    js(IR) {
        binaries.executable()
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
                implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
            }
        }
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-react:18.2.0-pre.346")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-react-dom:18.2.0-pre.346")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-emotion:11.9.3-pre.346")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-react-router-dom:6.3.0-pre.346")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-redux:4.1.2-pre.346")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-react-redux:7.2.6-pre.346")
            }
        }
        val jsTest by getting
    }
}

tasks.named<Copy>("jvmProcessResources") {
    val jsBrowserDistribution = tasks.named("jsBrowserDistribution")
    from(jsBrowserDistribution)
}
```

However, `./gradlew build` throws this

```
 ./gradlew clean build

> Configure project :
Kotlin Multiplatform Projects are an Alpha feature. See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/evolution/components-stability.html. To hide this message, add 
'kotlin.mpp.stability.nowarn=true' to the Gradle properties.

The property 'kotlin.mpp.enableGranularSourceSetsMetadata=true' has no effect in this and future Kotlin versions, as Hierarchical Structures support is now en
abled by default. It is safe to remove the property.

The property 'kotlin.native.enableDependencyPropagation=false' has no effect in this and future Kotlin versions, as Kotlin/Native dependency commonization is 
now enabled by default. It is safe to remove the property.


> Task :compileKotlinJvm FAILED
e: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.script.experimental.api.KotlinType.<init>(kotlin.reflect.KClass, boolean, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstru
ctorMarker)'
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.definitions.ScriptCompilationConfigurationFromDefinition$1.invoke(ScriptCompilationConfigurationFromDefinition.kt:32
)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.definitions.ScriptCompilationConfigurationFromDefinition$1.invoke(ScriptCompilationConfigurationFromDefinition.kt:28
)
        at kotlin.script.experimental.api.ScriptCompilationConfiguration.<init>(scriptCompilation.kt:23)
        at kotlin.script.experimental.api.ScriptCompilationConfiguration.<init>(scriptCompilation.kt:25)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.definitions.ScriptCompilationConfigurationFromDefinition.<init>(ScriptCompilationConfigurationFromDefinition.kt:27) 
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.definitions.ScriptDefinition$Companion.getDefault(ScriptDefinition.kt:221)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.ScriptingCompilerConfigurationExtension.updateConfiguration(ScriptingCompilerConfigurationExtension.
kt:67)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.configureProjectEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:578)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:199)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:108)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:445)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:192)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:143)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:47)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:475)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:125)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:373)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:318)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:207)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:625)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1746)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlinJvm'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5s
9 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

How to fix this?

Note that if I use version `1.6.21` (as suggested by https://start.spring.io/) for kotlin multiplatorm and kotlin spring plugin, then compiler is unable to resolve imports related to kotlin/js react

```
import kotlinx.browser.document
import react.create
import react.dom.client.createRoot
```

Comment: Applying Gradle plugins within the `jvm {}` block doesn't look right to me, what result do you want that to have?

Comment: When you use 1.6.21 and the imports don't work, what source set is the `.kt` file in? Is it in `jsMain` or `jvmMain`?

Comment: @aSemy .kt is in both sets

Comment: I think those imports will only work in the `jsMain` source set. They come from Kotlin/JS libraries.

Comment: This is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-53426.

Comment: @vanyochek yes, have seen that before posting the question. with some changes, the problem got resolved for the original poster there. but others and me still facing the issue.

Comment: Remove this line in parent project (do not apply io.spring.dependency-management plugin for all modules) and just apply it to the spring modules. 
apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")